# Dudas sobre concurrencia en servicios inyectados en ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, inyeccion-de-dependencias, singleton

Tengo un *servicio inyectado en el contenedor de servicios* del framework de **dotnet** **ASP.NET**.
Dicho servicio lo inyecto como un **Singleton**, y su función es la de mantener varias estructuras de datos (**Dictionay**, **List**, **Queue**) en memoria.

El servicio es perfectamente accesible desde los *controladores*, y mis dudas se deben al desconocimiento del funcionamiento interno de **ASP.NET**:

- ¿Debo yo preocuparme de crear el Singleton (*thread safe*) o se encarga el contenedor?
- ¿Los accesos a los métodos del sevicio, *son encolados en un único thread*?, o pueden ser *invocados concurrentemente*?. Lo pregunto por saber si he de utilizar **Colecciones concurrentes** en lugar de las genéricas.
- ¿Sería conveniente hacer los **métodos asíncronos**?

Acepto cualquier sugerencia.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: interesante.. pero la tercera, esta basada en opiniones.. (siempre que se pueda que sea async, mejor)... las otras no las entiendo mucho, si es un singleton, es uno para todas las llamadas, pero porque tenes colecciones en tus servicios? esto parece mas orientado al [chat]...

Comment: ah no habia visto esto: "y su función es la de mantener varias estructuras de datos (Dictionay, List, Queue) en memoria"... todo depende quien va a modificar la coleccion y como las vas a mantener...

Comment: Las colecciones están en memoria en el servicio. los metodos son invocados desde controladores tipicos asp.net

Comment: Antes de chatear, aclárame cual es el modelo de ejecución de asp.NET. un único hilo de proceso, los controlodores pueden invocar concurrentemente a los servicios?

Comment: yo no tengo ni idea (no me puse a investigarlo), lo digo, porque hay partes de tu pregunta que piden sugerencias, y hay multiples preguntas en una...

Comment: Pero seria raro que las llamadas estuvieran en un unico hilo.. si fuera asi, 1000 clientes esperando request estarian protestando en una cola infinita....

Comment: Tu último comentario.. es así como Node funciona. ASP:NET les habrá copiado. Me hago la pregunta pero no encuentro la respuesta. NO será así, pero no se desmiente en ningun sitio